# Error "The path is not of a legal form" on execute nuget pack

Tags: nuget, pack

I try to make a Nuget package for my solution made in c#, also this one has a lot of projects on that solution.

I running this script

```
.\nuget.exe pack PrincipalSolution.csproj -IncludeReferencedProjects -Build -Force -Properties "Configuration=Debug;Platform=x64" -Verbosity "detailed"
```

but i have this error on the Package Manager Console

```
System.ArgumentException: The path is not of a legal form.
   at System.IO.Path.LegacyNormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
   at System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(String path)
   at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(String path, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)
   at NuGet.CommandLine.ProjectFactory.GetFiles(String path, ISet`1 fileNames, SearchOption searchOption)
   at NuGet.CommandLine.ProjectFactory.AddOutputFiles(PackageBuilder builder)
   at NuGet.CommandLine.ProjectFactory.RecursivelyApply(Action`1 action, Object alreadyAppliedProjects)
   at NuGet.CommandLine.ProjectFactory.RecursivelyApply(Action`1 action, Object alreadyAppliedProjects)
   at NuGet.CommandLine.ProjectFactory.RecursivelyApply(Action`1 action)
   at NuGet.CommandLine.ProjectFactory.CreateBuilder(String basePath, NuGetVersion version, String suffix, Boolean buildIfNeeded, PackageBuilder builder)
   at NuGet.Commands.PackCommandRunner.BuildFromProjectFile(String path)
   at NuGet.Commands.PackCommandRunner.BuildPackage()
   at NuGet.CommandLine.PackCommand.ExecuteCommand()
   at NuGet.CommandLine.Command.ExecuteCommandAsync()
   at NuGet.CommandLine.Command.Execute()
   at NuGet.CommandLine.Program.MainCore(String workingDirectory, String[] args)
```

My project does not have any broken reference, is any other thing i should to validate or aggregate?

Thanks

Comment: Assuming you are using Visual Studio build tools here, you don't indicate what version.  If it is VS 2019 version, or if by other means you have gotten nuget 5.x and are using older (VS 2017) project files, you may have found this bug: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/vs-2019-165-nuget-package-manager-55-causes-the-pa/959974